# Windows Service not starting - Excel - Mail interops

Tags: c#, excel, windows, vb.net, service

My windows service won't start.

Installed correctly without errors and now it wont start. Standard UI message

[image]

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion.

My service is using `Excel.Interop` to create the .xls file and convert it to pdf. Then its using `System.Net.Mail` to mail the .pdf out

Is there any log file located to find out why it cant ?

Note:
   In debug mode everything works great but once installed doesn't work
   Realese .exe not working either

Comment: Office automation from a service is explicitly not supported or recommended, lots of things can go wrong - as you are experiencing.  The ideal thing to use is to perform your tasks from a desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Menu, then find/load **Event Viewer**. Probably find logs regarding that error by selecting Applications and Services logs inside the panel on the left in Event Viewer. Or on second thoughts,  under Windows Logs -> Application. Might have to explore a little.

Comment: I did not implemented Event log inside my service. Are you sure I'm able to see log here ?

Comment: Yer if you're running up a Windows Service it might have caught your exception in there but you may well need to add more logging for more detail and put some try/catch round some key elements like file access and connecting to send email. Often something like account permissions will silently timeout on a service.

Comment: Well looks like you are right. I just noticed on both machines this error logging `Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.6769.2040, time stamp: 0x571d7a72`

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct answer if it worked for you.

Comment: My problem still persist. I found the reason why but how ti fix it

Comment: Ah well you should maybe update the question. As you asked where to find logs for a service :) not enough info to diagnose your actual problem without the logging I suggested adding.